# How to configure apache so that the website works with and without www prefix

Tags: apache, web, configuration, webserver, prefix

I've installed `apache2` on my `ubuntu` server and it works fine **without** `www` prefix, but with it, it doesn't. How can I configure my server so that it does work in both cases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What do your DNS A-record and CNAME-record for this website look like? 
This should help:
http://support.simpledns.com/KB/a87/configure-web-site-access-with-without-www-domain-name.aspx